# Implement simple linear algebra operation in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Given some (n,m) matrix X with columns x_1, ..., x_m, I am trying to find an op that gives me either the 3-mode tensor [x_1 x_1^T, ..., x_m x_m^T] with shape (m, n,n) or the (n**2, m) matrix with columns vec(x_1 x_1^T),...,vec(x_m x_m^T) where vec is the vectorization of the matrices x_i x_i^T.

In other words, I am trying to generalize

```
tf.tensordot(a,a,axes=0)
```

or

```
tf.tensordot(a,a,axes=0).reshape(-1,1)
```

from vectors a to the columns of a matrix. Is there a way to get this done without having to rely on a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with:

```
tf.expand_dims(a, 2) @ tf.expand_dims(a, 1)
```

Or using [`tf.linalg.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul) instead of the `@` operator if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you. This way it will calculate the tensorproduct of the rows, but that is fine as well.